# Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor)

Tags: reactjs, derbyjs, racerjs

In the code below _updateQID method is triggered on emitting event 'Questions.updateHeader' by another component. when emitted event and triggered _updateQID i get below warning in console:

> Warning: forceUpdate(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { subscribe, model } from '~/lib'
import { ContextMenu } from 'project-components'
import _ from 'lodash'
import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3'

import './Headers.styl'



class Headers extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.ee = new EventEmitter()
        this._updateQID = this._updateQID.bind(this)
    }

  componentDidMount () {
    model.on('Questions.updateHeader', this._updateQID.bind(this))
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    model.removeListener('Questions.updateHeader', this._updateQID.bind(this))
  }


 _updateQID = () =>{
     this.forceUpdate()
  }


  render () {
    return (<div className="header">DUMMY TEST FOR HEADER</div>)
  }
}

export default Headers
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Okay we solved it... We were triggering the event to forceupdate Headers component from render method of another component.... After putting it into componentDidUpdate instead of render that warning was gone...

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can you share your code changes